# Designing a model with lights and sound. Looking for feedback regarding powering everything correctly

Tags: arduino, power, led, dc, speakers

[image]I know its early in the year, but I'm designing an Xmas decoration to be ready by December 1st while I've got some free time coming up.

The concept is a desktop wooden church that contains a 5W speaker hidden in the bell tower which will periodically play choral music stored on a SD card. As well as this there will be a chain of small LED fairy lights that will flash patterns(3 x red, 3 x blue, 3 x green, 3 x yellow), with some additional LEDS inside shining out through some frosted windows (3 x warm white).

This will all be controlled via an Arduino Nano.

Normally with arduino projects I am used to keeping things simple. Powering directly through the USB and pulling 5V from the board to whatever module I wanted to power. After approaching a similar project last year and getting unpredictable results I have decided that I should A.) Use an external power supply and B.) Think about a higher voltage to drive my speaker and LEDS. As this is the first time I am attempting running a circuit at different voltages I thought best to share my idea and see if anyone has any suggestions to improve the design.

I have opted to use a 9V transformer as my initial power supply and step down to 5V for the modules that need it. Lots of online tutorials suggest 9V batteries but that is something I'd like to avoid here.

I'm still working on my *wiring diagram* drawing abilities but I have attached an image.

Any feedback would be appreciated before I attempt to wire everything up. What am I overlooking? My design doesn't include decoupling capacitors at this stage. Most of the modules appear to have some form of capacitors built in but I'm open to adding more.

Comment: That's a wiring diagram not a circuit diagram. "Any feedback" you said.

Comment: There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar to enable you to embed the image in the post.

Comment: Getting the correct terminology is important, so thank you and apologies. I have made the appropriate edits.

Comment: Please, make an actual schematic, not a wiring diagram. It's quite difficult to read this.

Comment: Understood, I'll put more work into the design.

Comment: The datasheet of an LM386 power amplifier shows that with a 5V supply and a 4 ohm speaker the output power is only 0.16W but the IC heating is 0.35W. Your tiny 2" thing is a squeaker, not a speaker.

Comment: "LM386" and "5W speaker" do not belong together.

Comment: Clearly I've severely mismatched my components. Out of interest, could you point me to where in the datasheet it shows the links between 5V supply, 4ohms, 0.16W and 0.35W. It's not that I don't believe you, I just want to get better at reading this information to avoid making similar mistakes in the future. I've scoured the Typical Characteristics section but just cant make the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wiring diagram is fine. The only thing it doesn't show that might be important is the actual routing of the wires.

To prevent noise on the ground wire from causing glitches or audible noise you should connect the amplifier, LED driver and SD Card grounds directly to the regulator with the shortest wires practicable. Then connect the ground wire from the amp to the Arduino, again with the shortest practicable wiring length. This way current from the higher power modules will flow directly back to the regulator without affecting the Arduino, and ground noise between the Arduino and amp should be minimized.

For their [5V Step-Up/Step-Down Voltage Regulator S7V8F5](https://www.pololu.com/product/2123), Pololu recommend soldering a 33 μF or larger electrolytic capacitor (rated for 16 V or higher) close to the regulator between VIN and GND.

The LM386 can only produce about 300 mW into a 4 Ω load at 9 V. This may be loud enough with an efficient speaker, but the chip will run very hot. If you think you might need more volume then consider using a class D amp such as the [PAM8403](https://www.bitsbox.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=347&products_id=3877). I used one of these to replace an LM386 that *burned out* in a project similar to yours, even though I was only using an 8 Ω speaker on 5 V. The PAM8403 was much louder and produced almost no heat! Note that the PAM8403 must be powered from 5 V.

Comment: I'm really grateful that you took the time to break down some of the issue with my project. Your suggestions seem very reasonable and its been helpful to identify gaps in my knowledge.  
I would certainly like to increase the volume output so I appreciate you offering an alternative. I hope this will save me many headaches!